# Change Thousand separator location using custom format

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have local machine thousand separator setting as `00,00,00,000`. For just a single excel file, I want to change it to `000,000,000`

To achieve this, I am using this existing custom format.

```
[>=10000000]###\,###\,##0;[>=1000000]##\,###\,##0;##,##0
```

Now, the issue with this formatting is - It only works when the number of digits is less than `9`. if more than 9 it does not all any commas. Which makes this > `1234,567,981`

I tried using the custom format as

```
[>=1000000000000]###\,###\,###\,##0;[>=1000000000]###\,###\,##0;[>=1000000]##\,###\,##0;##,##0
```

Excel is not adding it. It gives an error. My best guess is there is a limit on a number of if that can be added to the custom format.

Any help is appreciated. I am open to using another method to achieve this.

Comment: In order to change the appearance in this manner, for just a **single excel file**, you will need to use VBA and present the results as a text string.

Answer (score 1):

As you're trying to get the default behavior of the number format just use the default number format.

Comment: the default number format in Excel is governed by local setting in Windows OS. I am trying to get `Non-Default` behavior of the number format

Comment: Oh OK. Kind of misread that. But if you chose to have that format to represent numbers, why would you need to change it for a single cell? For other people without that strange format setting it would already display like you want it to be. It doesn't look like it's possible to overwrite the digit grouping using a format in a "unlimited length" fashion.

Comment: Thanks `It doesn't look like it's possible` << I guess that's my answer.